# process.on() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I'm quite new to Node.js and I'm not sure to completely understand what this error actually means:

> process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
>
> ```
>    ^
> ```
>
> TypeError: process.on is not a function

I [read](https://flaviocopes.com/node-exceptions/) that one should not import `process` because it's automatically injected. My code is like this:

```
var settings;

var jsonfile = require("jsonfile");
var file = "server/settings.json";

try {
    var obj = jsonfile.readFileSync(file);
    settings = obj;

} catch (err) {
    var msg = err + ". Exiting";
    console.error(msg);
    throw new Error("Fatal");
}

// some other functions

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message)
    console.error(err.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  })

module.exports.login = login;
module.exports.logout = logout;
```

My intentions are to exit if I cannot read the settings file. This is by design.
I'm aware other approaches might be better, but my question is why I get the error above?

I'm running Node.js 8.12.0 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to add that, what you can do is use that right at the end of your app.js or server.js( whatever your file may be).

that will globally catch any uncaught errors and log them

```
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`app listening on port ${port}!`));

process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

so exporting is not necessary...

Answer (score 0):

You should move the process.on() function before the try catch, otherwise your uncaughtException event won't take effect.

```
var settings;

var jsonfile = require("jsonfile");
var file = "server/settings.json";

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message)
    console.error(err.stack)
    process.exit(1)
})

try {
    var obj = jsonfile.readFileSync(file);
    settings = obj;

} catch (err) {
    var msg = err + ". Exiting";
    console.error(msg);
    throw new Error("Fatal");
}
```